# Dropping C library on Linux w/GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, system-calls

I'm trying to create a basic application which is heavy on raw syscalls only, and I don't need the C library. I'm also trying to keep size to an absolute minimum. For functions like `strcpy`, `strcmp`, I'm hoping to use compiler intrinsics.

On Windows with MSVC/GCC I can use `/NODEFAULTLIB` or `-nostdlib` to detach from the C standard library. Then I'll simply link to `kernel32.lib`, `user32.lib`, to use functions like `WriteFile`, `CreateWindowExW`, etc. I'm trying to do the same on linux but I'm running into a few problems.

It seems like for some reason, the code of the syscalls `read`, `write`, `ptrace,` `process_vm_readv`, etc are actaully in gclib? I tried to use `syscall(SYS_write, ...)` as well as I was hoping that'd be inlined into my program somehow but that still needs gclib. Is there a way to call these syscalls like on Windows, where I'd link to a system library instead of the C library? I'd like to avoid writing the syscall stubs myself using inline ASM. I'm starting to work with linux programming like this so I'm not too sure. Here's a simple test application I'm using (which isn't compiling):

```
#include <unistd.h>

void ProcessEntry()
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Detached from CRT", 18);
    _exit(0);
}
```

I'm using the command: `gcc -c program.c` and `ld program.o -nostdlib -e ProcessEntry`.

Comment: Linux has no such thing as "a system library".  If you don't want libc then you are completely on your own; you have access to no code except that which you write (or import) for yourself.  In particular, the only way to invoke a system call is via (inline or out-of-line) asm, or a pre-written macro or function that does so.

Comment: On the other hand, whatever it is you're trying to save by not linking with libc, I'll bet a lot that it's a false economy.

Comment: UNIX was written in C, and C was *invented* to write UNIX. So the C library *is* the UNIX system library.

Comment: "`I'm also trying to keep size to an absolute minimum`" Dynamic linking to external libraries (like glibc) is a good way to minimize the size of your executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I got:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

// Copied from MUSL libc
// There are more at
// http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/x86_64/syscall_arch.h
static __inline long __syscall1(long n, long a1) {
  unsigned long ret;
  __asm__ __volatile__("syscall"
                       : "=a"(ret)
                       : "a"(n), "D"(a1)
                       : "rcx", "r11", "memory");
  return ret;
}

void do_exit(int status) { __syscall1(SYS_exit, status); }

void entry() { do_exit(5); }
```

Saved as syscall.c and compiled with

```
cc -Wall -W -pedantic -static -O3 -march=native -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects  -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -std=gnu18 -nostdlib -e entry  syscall.c   -o syscall
```

And this is the entire disassembly of the 9,224 byte program:

```
0000000000001000 <entry>:
    1000:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1004:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
    1009:   bf 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%edi
    100e:   0f 05                   syscall
    1010:   c3                      retq
```